# Git tfs - sequence has no elements

Tags: git, tfs, git-tfs

I am migrating a tfs project to git and am using the latest version .20 of git tfs and have converted my project into branch in tfs and am still facing this error. Here is the log of what I get:

```
Setting up a TFS workspace at .git\tfs\default\workspace
get [C39462]$/Dow Jones Infrastructure/trunk/src/DowJones.Web.Mvc/DowJones.Web.M
vc.csproj
C39462 = cdacbb91c508cd75c305547f9fa91d8f7225d87d
GC Countdown: 181
Cleaning...
Sep.Git.Tfs.Core.GitTfsException: error: a problem occured when trying to clone
the repository. Try to solve the problem described below.
In any case, after, try to continue using command `git tfs fetch`
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Max(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Sep.Git.Tfs.Core.GitTfsRemote.ProcessMergeChangeset(ITfsChangeset changese
t, Boolean stopOnFailMergeCommit, String& parentCommit)
   at Sep.Git.Tfs.Core.GitTfsRemote.FetchWithMerge(Int64 mergeChangesetId, Boole
an stopOnFailMergeCommit, String[] parentCommitsHashes)
   at Sep.Git.Tfs.Commands.Fetch.DoFetch(IGitTfsRemote remote, Boolean stopOnFai
lMergeCommit)
   at Sep.Git.Tfs.Commands.Fetch.FetchRemote(Boolean stopOnFailMergeCommit, IGit
TfsRemote remote)
   at Sep.Git.Tfs.Commands.Fetch.Run(Boolean stopOnFailMergeCommit, String[] arg
s)
   at Sep.Git.Tfs.Commands.Clone.Run(String tfsUrl, String tfsRepositoryPath, St
ring gitRepositoryPath)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Sep.Git.Tfs.Util.GitTfsCommandRunner.Run(GitTfsCommand command, IList`1 ar
gs)
   at Sep.Git.Tfs.GitTfs.Main(GitTfsCommand command, IList`1 unparsedArgs)
   at Sep.Git.Tfs.Program.Main(String[] args)
error: a problem occured when trying to clone the repository. Try to solve the p
roblem described below.
In any case, after, try to continue using command `git tfs fetch`

System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Max(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Sep.Git.Tfs.Core.GitTfsRemote.ProcessMergeChangeset(ITfsChangeset changese
t, Boolean stopOnFailMergeCommit, String& parentCommit)
   at Sep.Git.Tfs.Core.GitTfsRemote.FetchWithMerge(Int64 mergeChangesetId, Boole
an stopOnFailMergeCommit, String[] parentCommitsHashes)
   at Sep.Git.Tfs.Commands.Fetch.DoFetch(IGitTfsRemote remote, Boolean stopOnFai
lMergeCommit)
   at Sep.Git.Tfs.Commands.Fetch.FetchRemote(Boolean stopOnFailMergeCommit, IGit
TfsRemote remote)
   at Sep.Git.Tfs.Commands.Fetch.Run(Boolean stopOnFailMergeCommit, String[] arg
s)
   at Sep.Git.Tfs.Commands.Clone.Run(String tfsUrl, String tfsRepositoryPath, St
ring gitRepositoryPath)
Sequence contains no elements
```

here's my git tfs clone command:

```
 PS:if your branch is not listed here, perhaps you should convert the containing
folder to a branch in TFS.
Fetching from TFS remote 'default'...
C39287 = 32b95538d87efab00ada41347069bfaf5b2eb1aa
C39347 = 88e584492a318ad520d4caaa94202620f968281b
C39348 = 34faf002c3ec8a2a52296472a35493523f164d75
C39351 = b2c7b256a5c5f58b88c1c879f2b2e08051ed4125
C39353 = c2fb6988f8f92803c4bd9fc81638b68d7867dbc7
C39355 = e5e364b2ccfe19a72d1a42c0e58c25a32389033c
C39356 = 64850cb6e181c04463affead17840e0d23780a4a
C39357 = 518c57ed83f115f602c722acc9c6cf21e11a6260
C39359 = 3ab61d15a7d84cb2d0de5f7e0cbb6a038cad28fb
C39360 = a92963812c6184d72a39ff35faf754b784bccaab
C39393 = 25b6385094b4165f22d12bd8880fde7cdbc607af
C39407 = f6c9d31b0f21b6e9bf7f8e7611f9efd79068cb7d
C39408 = 0c13bf39f416feee8428cf49d14148723b3a2061
C39409 = e0d4a70e8a221078bfb585a8b5e5cf59da77ff7d
C39411 = b459848e0093babbc8260bdb52d3072699d2184e
C39451 = b7fc45fb08b907f68cec48fbbca01b6c4fb99c6a
C39454 = e022581df4b5e164e14910112229eae37d8681f5
C39456 = 696657332c22091d92dbb5de4316711ac4d0c7d9
C39461 = f5c5736f4230233f4cbaf4bba0f8f72c378df52b
C39462 = cdacbb91c508cd75c305547f9fa91d8f7225d87d
error: a problem occured when trying to clone the repository. Try to solve the p
roblem described below.
In any case, after, try to continue using command `git tfs fetch`

Sequence contains no elements
```

Heres the commit I think its giving problem on :

> Merging DJ_Component branch with Component JS re-architecting
>
> Chadwick, Jess checked in changeset 39571 4 years ago 13 files edited3
>   files deleted

Even after I ignore the commit, it successfully migrates some more commits before failing with the same error again!

Comment: @Philippe - Please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

I see you [reported the error](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/issues/637) on the Git-Tfs project site, and the issue was marked as fixed two weeks ago.

Can you get the latest code, build it and see if it works for you? Alternatively wait for the 0.21 release and try that instead.